# Web scraping sites with different layouts (with user's consent)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, web-scraping

I have a site on which users can post blog entries, they can write them themselves, but I would also like to give them an option of importing their existing entries from blog sites they may already have (no worries, only users themselves will upload their own content if they choose to do so). The main problem, however is, that nowadays each user can customize his/her blog appearance, which means that even two users, who both use the same site (for example blogspot or wordpress) can have completely different layout, and div naming.
Is there a way to somehow scrape these entries with a "generic" method or something?

And before anyone suggests RSS, I have tried that, but I want whole entries to be uploaded on my site and only blogspot seems to store them like that in RSS, plus, users will choose which entry to upload, not the whole blog and that means they can choose an entry from quite a whie back, which RSS does not store anymore.

I am using Ruby on Rails 3, and have so far tried scraping with Nokogiri.

Comment: Wordpress has an 'export' option in the admin console, blogspot might have similar. It exports as XML, so you could still use Nokogiri. Should be way more standardized than web scraping the actual site.

Comment: This is pretty useful, blogspot also has it, but what I would like nevertheless is support for as many different blogs as possible. Also, with scraping the user simply copies a link and pastes it to my site and the app does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There's a written gem for webscraping, it is the [MECHANIZE GEM](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/).
It's quite easy and useful. This and some [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) shinanigans should do the trick.

Comment: I am already using a gem for scraping, Nokogiri and have no problems to scrape a site with a fixed layout, but my problem is that users can have pretty useless layouts. The best ones have content in a div with id "entry" or something and the title in a header with id "entry-title" and that is easy to scrape, but some just have nothing to really help me tell apart different components and that is my problem.